# snort | pcre| rule specification

Tags: pcre, snort

My objective is to write a rule to detect a simple truth exploit (**SQLi**)

The string example is of a form:

```
% ' or 1 = 1 #
```

In order to identify the string above and some of its variations, I have developed following pcre.

```
pcre: "/\W\s*\W\s*or\s*([\d\w])\s*\W\s*\1\s*\W/";
```

I ran a test @ [regextester](http://www.regextester.com/) and my regex seems to work. However, in Snort, this rule fails to pick and does not trigger.

The rule is of a format

```
alert 192.168.x.x any -> 192.168.y.y 80 (msg: "SQL Query"; pcre: "/\W\s*\W\s*or\s*([\d\w])\s*\W\s*\1\s*\W/"; sid: 1001;);
```

I'd appreciate any help

**GET** request from *Whireshark*

```
GET /dvwa/vulnerabilities/sqli/?id=%25+%27+or+1+%3D+1+%23&Submit=Submit
```

Comment: Did you get error message like `Rule options must be enclosed in '(' and ')'`? You do not need a `;` at the end of the rule.

Comment: It does not produce an error, the other two rules in the file are working fine except this one

Comment: It may be easier to get help if you included a pcap of the traffic.

Comment: @Mr.kang i added the get request to my op

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the rule fail is URL encoding. `%25` means `%`, `%27`means `'`, `+(or %20)` means `space`, `%3D` means `=`. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Snort have a `HTTP normalization module`. But i think it is not perfect.

Refer to following rule.

```
alert tcp any any -> any any (content:"+or+"; nocase; pcre:"/\+or\+\w\+%3D\+\w/";)
```

Using pcre alone can degrade performance. When used with content, it narrows the scope of the pcre inspection and improves performance.